unable to loop through key values of object and add them to a StringBuffer
im having issues encoding key value pairs inside of UrlFormatter.encode_params.
when i do it outside it works.
code1:
List<Map<String, dynamic>> table_query_params = [];
    Map<String, dynamic> tqp1 = {
      'column': 'sys_id',
      'operator': '=',
      'value': "'${widget.column['sys_table_id1']}'"
    };
    table_query_params.add(tqp1);
    Map<String, dynamic> tqp2 = {'limit': '10', 'query_type': "'limit_by'"};
    table_query_params.add(tqp2);
    //
    StringBuffer encoded_params = StringBuffer();

    print("aaaaaaa");
    tqp2.forEach((key, value) {
      print("key: $key");
      print("value: $value");
      String param = '$key!=true';
      print("PARAM: $param");
      encoded_params.write(param);
    });
    print("encoded_params: ${encoded_params}");

    /////

    String table_query_encoded_query =
        UrlFormatter.encode_params(table_query_params);


code2:
 static String encode_params(List<Map<String, dynamic>> key_value_pairs) {
    StringBuffer encoded_params = StringBuffer();

    for (Map<String, dynamic> pair in key_value_pairs) {
      try {
        if (!pair.containsKey('column')) {
          print("NO COLUMN ${pair}");
          pair.forEach((key, value) {
            print("key: $key");
            print("value: $value");
            String param = '$key!=true';
            print("PARAM: $param");
            encoded_params.write(param);
          });
        } else {
          String column = Uri.encodeComponent(pair['column'].toString());
          String operator;
          if (pair.containsKey('operator')) {
            operator = Uri.encodeComponent(pair['operator'].toString());
          } else {
            operator = Uri.encodeComponent('=');
          }
          String value = '';
          if (pair.containsKey('value')) {
            if (pair['value'] is Map || pair['value'] is List) {
              value = json.encode(pair['value']);
            } else {
              value = pair['value']?.toString() ?? '';
            }
            value = Uri.encodeComponent(value);
          }

          if (encoded_params.length > 0) {
            encoded_params.write('&');
          }
          encoded_params.write('$column=$operator=$value');
        }
      } catch (e) {
        print('Error encoding URL parameters: $e');
      }
    }

    return encoded_params.toString();
  }


output::
Restarted application in 82ms.
The debugEmulateFlutterTesterEnvironment getter is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use `debugEmulateFlutterTesterEnvironment` from `dart:ui_web` instead.
_ui_type: record
_ui_view: admin_sys_menu_category
_query_params: sys_active=%3D=true
_get_view_columns()

_get_columns_data()

CKICK
_on_icon_click()

aaaaaaa
key: limit
value: 10
PARAM: limit!=true
key: query_type
value: 'limit_by'
PARAM: query_type!=true
encoded_params: limit!=truequery_type!=true
NO COLUMN {limit: 10, query_type: 'limit_by'}
key: limit
value: 10
PARAM: limit!=true
key: query_type
value: 'limit_by'
PARAM: query_type!=true
Error: RangeError (index): Index out of range: no indices are valid: 0
http://localhost:56797/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 294:49       throw_
http://localhost:56797/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/js_array.dart 591:7                  _get]
http://localhost:56797/dart-sdk/lib/internal/cast.dart 99:38                                              _get
http://localhost:56797/packages/worknow_front_end/ui/components/columns/list_field/list_field.dart 32:21  _on_icon_click
http://localhost:56797/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 45:50                 <fn>
http://localhost:56797/dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1661:54                                               runUnary
http://localhost:56797/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 156:18                                         handleValue
http://localhost:56797/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 840:44                                         handleValueCallback
http://localhost:56797/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 869:13                                         _propagateToListeners
http://localhost:56797/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 641:5                                          [_completeWithValue]
http://localhost:56797/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 715:7                                          callback
http://localhost:56797/dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 40:11                                   _microtaskLoop
http://localhost:56797/dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 49:5                                    _startMicrotaskLoop
http://localhost:56797/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 181:15                <fn>


i know the issue is below but i dont know where.
if (!pair.containsKey('column')) {
          print("NO COLUMN ${pair}");
          pair.forEach((key, value) {
            print("key: $key");
            print("value: $value");
            String param = '$key!=true';
            print("PARAM: $param");
            encoded_params.write(param);
          });

i am printing the variables before adding it to encoded_params so not sure what the issue is.
i am able to iterate through the key/value pairs out side of Uri.encodeComponent.
i didnt find any similar stack overflows.
the expected result should be that the system does not crash.

"i know the issue is below but i dont know where." What makes you believe that?  I don't see any evidence for that: 1. Your code doesn't print anything after print("PARAM: $param");, so there's no upper-bound for where the error could be.  2. The exception is a RangeError from trying to access an empty List, but nowhere in your code do you access any Lists by index. 3. The code that you think is erroneous is within a try-catch block (which is a bad idea) that would catch any thrown RangeError anyway.
